# vr view android, how to get image from URL

Tags: android, android-studio, virtual-reality

based on VR View sample code tutorial, how to get panorama image from url or database ?

Since the sample tutorial is load default image load assets manager and i want to know how to load it from internet/URL image link.

here my first activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_kuliner);

    //INITIALIZE VIEWS
    nama_kul = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameDetail_kul);
    lokasi_kul = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lokasi_kul);
    desclong_kul = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.desclong_kul);
    image_kul = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageDetail_kul);

    //RECEIVE DATA
    Intent intent=this.getIntent();
    String name_kul=intent.getExtras().getString("NAME_KEY");
    String lokas_kul=intent.getExtras().getString("LOKASI_KEY");
    final String descshor_kul=intent.getExtras().getString("DESCSHORT_KEY");
    String desclon_kul=intent.getExtras().getString("DESCLONG_KEY");
    final String images_kul=intent.getExtras().getString("IMAGE_KEY");

    //BIND DATA
    nama_kul.setText(name_kul);
    lokasi_kul.setText(lokas_kul);
    desclong_kul.setText(desclon_kul);
    Glide.with(this).load(images_kul).into(image_kul);

    //Intent to 2nd activity
    detail2ButtonStart = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.detail2_but);
    detail2ButtonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(detail_kuliner.this, detail2_kuliner.class);
            intent.putExtra("DESCSHORT2_KEY",descshor_kul);
            intent.putExtra("IMAGE2_KEY",images_kul);

            //open activity
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

and this is my second activity

```
public class detail2_kuliner extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = detail2_kuliner.class.getSimpleName();
private VrPanoramaView panoWidgetView;
public boolean loadImageSuccessful;
private Uri fileUri;
private Options panoOptions = new Options();
private ImageLoaderTask backgroundImageLoaderTask;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail2_kuliner);
    panoWidgetView = (VrPanoramaView) findViewById(R.id.pano_view);
    panoWidgetView.setEventListener(new ActivityEventListener());
    handleIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, this.hashCode() + ".onNewIntent()");
    setIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Log.i(TAG, "ACTION_VIEW Intent recieved");

        fileUri = intent.getData();
        if (fileUri == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "No data uri specified. Use \"-d /path/filename\".");
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Using file " + fileUri.toString());
        }

        panoOptions.inputType = intent.getIntExtra("inputType", Options.TYPE_MONO);
        Log.i(TAG, "Options.inputType = " + panoOptions.inputType);
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Intent is not ACTION_VIEW. Using default pano image.");
        fileUri = null;
        panoOptions.inputType = Options.TYPE_MONO;
    }

    if (backgroundImageLoaderTask != null) {
        backgroundImageLoaderTask.cancel(true);
    }
    backgroundImageLoaderTask = new ImageLoaderTask();
    backgroundImageLoaderTask.execute(Pair.create(fileUri, panoOptions));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    panoWidgetView.pauseRendering();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    panoWidgetView.resumeRendering();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    panoWidgetView.shutdown();

    if (backgroundImageLoaderTask != null) {
        backgroundImageLoaderTask.cancel(true);
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

class ImageLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<Pair<Uri, Options>, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Pair<Uri, Options>... fileInformation) {
        Options panoOptions = null;  
        InputStream istr = null;
        if (fileInformation == null || fileInformation.length < 1
                || fileInformation[0] == null || fileInformation[0].first == null) {
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

            try {
                istr = new URL("http://SOME URL IMAGE").openStream(); //How to get SOME URL IMAGE from intent sent at first activity

                panoOptions = new Options();
                panoOptions.inputType = Options.TYPE_STEREO_OVER_UNDER;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not decode default bitmap: " + e);
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            try {
                istr = new FileInputStream(new File(fileInformation[0].first.getPath()));
                panoOptions = fileInformation[0].second;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not load file: " + e);
                return false;
            }
        }
  panoWidgetView.loadImageFromBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr), panoOptions);
        try {
            istr.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not close input stream: " + e);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

so i want to adding the VR View to second activity with the data that came with the intent, the data is from the database that sent by json format, based on this tutorial [VR View for android](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/vr_view_app_101/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#6) can i put the data with the intent from first activity to second activity (SOME URL IMAGE)?

thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can use Picasso, Glide or imageloader:  example below:

```
 Picasso.with(mContext)
.load("yoururl")
.config(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
.error(R.drawable.blank)
.centerInside()
.into(imageView);
```

Comment: i see that, i have an intent to pass data from the jason array at the another activity before, so can i pass a data (url image link) within the intent to the next activity that showing VR View frame

Answer (score -1):

Actually You can't get live from server, first you need to download from serve into your project and then use it from where you save that image in sdcard or internal folder.thanks..